# SQL Server Data Type Change

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, types, database-administration

In SQL Server, We have table with 80 million of records and 3 column data type is float right now. Now we need to change the float data type column into Decimal column. How to proceed it with minimum downtime?

We executed the usual ALTER statement to change the data type, but log file got filled and going to system out of memory exception. So kindly let me the better way to solve this issue.

We cant use this technique Like: Creating 3 new temp columns and updating the existing data batch wise and dropping the existing column and renaming the temp column to live columns.

Answer (score 1):

I have done exactly same in one of my project. Here are the steps which you can follow where minimal logging, minimum downtime with least complexity.

1. Create new table with new data types with same column names (Without index if table require any index create once data will be loaded in new table) but different name. For example existing table is EMPLOYEE then new table name should be EMPLOYEE_1. Keep in mind all constraints like foreign key and all you can create before loading or after loading it is not going to impact anything in terms of performance. But recommend don't create as existing table is having so names of constraints you have rename after renaming the table.
2. Keep in mind have max precision in new data type at what max precision value is available in your existing table.
3. Load data from your existing table to new table using SSIS with fast load option so that logging will not happen in temp database.
4. Rename the old table with EMPLOYEE_2 during downtime and rename the EMPLOYEE_1 to EMPLOYEE.
5. Alter table definition for foreign key, default or any other constrains.
6. Go live and create indexes in lower load time on table.

by using this approach we have changed the table data type where we had about more than billions records. Using this approach you can have minimum downtime and logging into tempDB as SSIS fast load option will not log anything in database.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

One of these approaches might work.

The simplest approach is to give up.  Well almost, but do the following:

- Rename the existing column to something else (say, `_col`)
- Add a computed column that does the conversion.

If the data is infrequently modified (so you only need read access), then create a new table.  That is, copy the data in to a new table with the correct type, then drop the original table and rename the new table to the old name.

You can do something similar by swapping table spaces rather than renaming the table.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be:

- Add a new column to the table with the correct datatype.
- Insert the values from the float column to the decimal column, but do it in bulk of x records.
- When everything is done, remove the float column and rename the decimal column to what the float column name was.